# Socks5 Protocol Error PhantomJS

Tags: proxy, phantomjs, socks

I wrote a simple PhantomJS script which automates a process on a website. A part of this process is submitting a form. I've been using this simple program for months using a quality proxy provider. Recently I switched providers and now I'm unable to bypass the form. Upon further testing (setting proxy on local computer) I found that using the proxy as socks rather than http allows me to bypass the form as needed.

However, when trying to set "--proxy-type=socks5" I get an error:

```
Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(UnknownNetworkError) ( "SOCKS version 5 protocol error" ) URL: "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json%27"
```

The command line I am trying to run is:

```
phantomjs --debug --proxy-type=socks5 --proxy=69.46.80.98:16151 ip.js
```

The content of ip.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');
var page = new WebPage(), testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;
page.setReferrer = false;

var userAgents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
];

var sessionAgent = userAgents[Math.floor(Math.random() * userAgents.length)];

page.settings.userAgent = sessionAgent;
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 600000;
page.settings.loadImages = false;

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log("load finished");
};

var steps = [
    function() {
        page.open('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json%27');
    },
    function() {
        console.log( page.plainText );
    }
];

interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
        console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
        steps[testindex]();
        testindex++;
    }
    if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
        console.log("test complete!");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}, 50);
```

The full debugging output:

```
root@earth:~# phantomjs --debug=true --proxy-type=socks5 --proxy=69.46.80.98:16151 /home/phantomjs/downloaders/ip.js
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Created but will not store cookies (use option '--cookies-file=<filename>' to enable persistent cookie storage)
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG] Set  "socks5"  proxy to:  "69.46.80.98" : 16151
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Configuration
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      0 objectName : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      1 cookiesFile : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      2 diskCacheEnabled : "false"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      3 maxDiskCacheSize : "-1"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      4 diskCachePath : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      5 ignoreSslErrors : "false"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      6 localUrlAccessEnabled : "true"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      7 localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled : "false"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      8 outputEncoding : "UTF-8"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      9 proxyType : "socks5"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      10 proxy : "69.46.80.98:16151"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      11 proxyAuth : ":"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      12 scriptEncoding : "UTF-8"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      13 webSecurityEnabled : "true"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      14 offlineStoragePath : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      15 localStoragePath : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      16 localStorageDefaultQuota : "-1"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      17 offlineStorageDefaultQuota : "-1"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      18 printDebugMessages : "true"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      19 javascriptCanOpenWindows : "true"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      20 javascriptCanCloseWindows : "true"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      21 sslProtocol : "default"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      22 sslCiphers : "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      23 sslCertificatesPath : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      24 sslClientCertificateFile : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      25 sslClientKeyFile : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      26 sslClientKeyPassphrase : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      27 webdriver : ":"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      28 webdriverLogFile : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      29 webdriverLogLevel : "INFO"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      30 webdriverSeleniumGridHub : ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Script & Arguments
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG]      script: "/home/phantomjs/downloaders/ip.js"
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Starting normal mode
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
step 1
2017-12-17T10:48:36 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
load started
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] skipping hostname of len 13
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(UnknownNetworkError) ( "SOCKS version 5 protocol error" ) URL: "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json%27"
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100
load finished
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
step 2

test complete!
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-12-17T10:48:37 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If proxy is working this could be due to SSL errors. Try using these switches in command-line:

```
 --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors
```